# Transform acceleration from phone to car axis

Tags: android, vector, sensors, android-sensors

Scenario:

1. The user is placing his phone and attaching it directly to car. Let's say by using tape. ( it can be laying in whatever position user want )
2. The user is clicking `Calibrate` which stores the current information about acceleration in some variable. Let say: `calibrationAcc = double[]{0,0,9.81}` would be the values, when to phone is facing `up`.
3. The user is accelerating in his car, so I am receiving `currectAcc`, obviously together with gravity forces.

As far as I understand, to get rough acceleration (without gravity) the only thing I need to do is to subtract form `currentAcceleration` the values from calibration. So it would be:

```
roughAcc = currentAcc - calibrationAcc
```

And now, my `roughAcc` contains the vector with values related only with pure car acceleration. But since I don't know the position in which the phone is placed inside the car ( it can be placed as a camera let's say ) I don't know how to transform my `roughAcc` into car's coordinate system. I want to have values in form:

```
carAcc {
    x // left or right car, increased in corners
    y // front or back car, increased when accelerating
    z // up or down, increased on bumps
}
```

I am missing something here. The simplest problem, I could not solve with the data I have ( using only the calibration vector ) is the situation, when user places the phone flat in the car ( so that `calibration = {0,0,9.8}`. Even in this situation, I cannot read clear what part of the acceleration is `carAcc.x` and which is `carAcc.y`, since I don't know the position of the phone inside the car ( if it is placed with `x` axis to the front of the car, or `y`, or if it is askew.

So, in terms of math and vector operations, what do I need to have to rotate `roughAcc` into `carAcc` and how to do it.

Comment: Given how noisy the accelerometers are, have you thought about using the GPS and compass to orient the device (provided the orientation doesn't change during the trip).

Comment: I thought about it, but compass is even less precise than acc, especially when used inside a car. When comes to gps/gyro, I could check if the movement is straight so that the measured `roughAcc` during this movement give me a direction of the forward acc. But still, I don't know how mathematically solve it...